# Counting the most frequent sequence occurring in a string

Tags: python, list, tuples, sequence, find-occurrences

Full Code is here: https://nekobin.com/yehukomiya
(Don't mind the *computeFile()* function)
Hi, I've got a text file with repeating chars in binary string like "0101001001111000010010011110010000000" I already got the *KMPSearch()* function that I use to count how many times a given sequence occurs in my string. I also count in the *ex1()* function the char that occurs most in the string, but what I want to achieve is find the most frequent ***sequence*** and how many times it occurs, and return the n sequences that repeat the most.
e.g.
`s = "01010010010001000111101100001010011001111000010010011110010000000"`
`n = 20`
I want to return the following list:

```
[     
      (4, ['0001', '0011', '1100' ]),
      (5, ['011', '1000', '110' ]),
      (6, ['0000', '111']),
      (7, ['0010','1001' ]),
      (8, ['0100']),
      (10,['010']),
      (11,['000', '001', '11']),
      (12,['100']),
      (15,['01','10']),
      (23,['00'])
]
```

Where the firs column is the m-times the sequences occurs, the following column are the actual sequences that repeat themselves m times, and the number of entry in the list is n.
It returns all the occurrences because n is less than the number of the occurrences it found.
but if n was for example equal to 4 I wanted the list:

```
[
      (11,['000', '001', '11']),
      (12,['100']),
      (15,['01','10']),
      (23,['00'])
]
```

At the end I would also like to sort the final tuple as shown.
Thank you all for your time and patience.

Comment: Are you limited to python standard library or are you allowed to use external packages?

Comment: @Daweo I'm limited to standard library unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rather straightforward, unoptimized way to approach this is in 2 steps could be (explanation below):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

s = "01010010010001000111101100001010011001111000010010011110010000000"

min_seq_length = 2

# 1. Count recurring sequences
sequence_dict = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for seq_start in range(len(s)):
    for seq_end in range(seq_start + min_seq_length, len(s)+1):
        sequence = s[seq_start:seq_end]
        sequence_dict[sequence] += 1

# 2. Group sequences by number of occurrences
grouped_sequences_dict = defaultdict(list)
for sequence, count in sequence_dict.items():
    if count > 1:
        grouped_sequences_dict[count].append(sequence)

# 3. Sort and filter grouped sequences
sorted_sequences = sorted(list(grouped_sequences_dict.items()))

top_n_results = 4
top_sequences = sorted_sequences[-top_n_results:]

for seq in top_sequences:
    print(seq)
```

output

```py
(11, ['001', '000', '11'])
(12, ['100'])     
(15, ['01', '10'])
(23, ['00'])
```

explanation:

1. **Count recurring sequences** by iterating over all substrings of at least 2 characters and building a dictionary to keep track how many times every unique sequences occurs:

   - sequence_dict's **key** is a unique sequence (e.g. `'00'`)
   - sequence_dict's **value** is the amount of occurrences
2. **Group sequences by number of occurrences** by iterating over all above sequences and building a dictionary that keeps a list of all sequences, per amount of occurrences:

   - `grouped_sequences_dict`'s **key** is the amount of occurrences
   - `grouped_sequences_dict`'s **value** is a list of sequences that occur this amount of times
3. **Sort and filter grouped sequences**

   - convert above dictionary to a list of (key,value) pairs
   - sort it (default sorting of a tuple will be done on the first item of the tuple, which is the key of above dictionary, being the amount of times a sequence occurs
   - take the last n (4) items

Could probably be optimized/simplified with a pandas.

## [edit] your code

My apologies, I just realized you provided a whole bunch of code already. It looks like you are already covering some aspects. Maybe an additional general remark: try to write the code as **pythonic** as possible, e.g.:

- avoid using meaningless variable names (M,N,i,j etc.)
- avoid using **while loops** and increments when it is possible to use **for loops** on **ranges**, or even better **for loops** on **iterables** (or even better, list comprehension if applicable)

This will make your code much more readable for yourself and for others

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I forgot to tell you, that I can't use libs, only standard python

Comment: The `defaultdict` I'm using can easily be replaced by a regular dictionary, e.g. `sequence_dict = {}`. When counting values, you should check whether or not the key already exists, e.g.: `sequence_dict[sequence] = (sequence_dict[sequence] + 1) if sequence in sequence_dict else 1`